# What's electropositive ion flux in a plasma?

Tags: plasma-physics

Is it the similar to the plasma density ? Or is it directly proportional to the plasma density ?

Comment: "Flux" sounds like it's some sort density times flow velocity. Could you provide some context as to where you came across this term?

Comment: @AndréasSundström Yes I came across this reading a research paper. You can see the paper here, https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0957-0233/23/8/085001/meta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, the "electropositive ion flux" from [this paper which the OP is referring to](https://doi.org/10.1088/0957-0233/23/8/085001), looks like it is the *flux of positively charged ions* or possibly flux of ions of species with an affinity towards becoming positively charged. In other words, it's the number of ions passing through a unit area per unit time, which should be proportional to the number density of positive ions.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Could you please look into the following question too please. It's about plasma generation. The link is here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/515067/does-the-following-plasma-visually-looks-like-capacitively-coupled-plasma-ccp

Comment: @user17195 I unfortunately do not have any experience at all in the field of cold plasmas. So I'm afraid I can't help you with that question.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the consideration.

Comment: Could you please see if you can answer this question. The link: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/519686/could-plasma-be-generated-when-there-is-a-dielectric-on-the-electrodes-see-que

Comment: @IndulaMunasinghe Sorry, I really don't know enough about these types of plasmas to answer your question. Maybe it would be worth for you to try to ask the question on the Engineering Stack Exchange.